# Allow illegal characters in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, httpwebrequest

I have created a textbox for my users to enter their comments. So, sometimes they copy the error that has been raised in the application and paste in the textbox along with comments. It may include illegal characters (eg. `</11>`) but it should be saved but my .aspx is not allowing. I don't know how to handle this. thanks!

Comment: _"my .aspx is not allowing"_ What code do you use to save, and what error do you get?

Comment: Consider my answer: maipulating text inserted by user with javascript, but keeping RequestValidation on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want **user to edit TextBox and enter html tags**  you can disable this via

```
 <%@ Page validateRequest="false" ...>
```

or in the web.config for your entire application:

```
<system.web>
  <page validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

> Note that this ValidateRequest property is not existing without
>   reason. When you change its default value, insecure input will be
>   accepted. Because of that, you need to validate every user's input to
>   avoid cross-site scripting attacks, like inserting of malicious
>   JavaScript, ActiveX, Flash or HTML

---

Another smart solution is to **replace via javascript text written by user** to make it safe for validation.
`< anyword>` , instead of `<anyword>` is considered safe!

```
function validateTxt() {
    $("textarea, input[type='text']").change(function () {
      html = $(this).val(); //get the value
      //.replace("a" , "b")  works only on first occurrence of "a"
      html = html.replace(/< /g, "<"); //before: if there's space after < remove
      html = html.replace(/</g, "< "); // add space after <
      $(this).val(html); //set new value
   });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
      validateTxt();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do you mean, we can solve this problem either by a space before or after the illegal character. If so, do we have to do for all illegal characters ?

Comment: My solution solves the problem of "<" character, which is illegal since allows user to generate HTML tags. "<anyword>" is considere a tag, instead "< anyword>" (there is a space) is not considered a tag, and it's allowed. What other illegal character do you know?

Answer (score 3):

i assume you are talking about an exception message like "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client..."

that is the asp.net request validation in action.  this can be disabled at the page or site level, but there are risks associated with doing so.

it is done with ValidateRequest="false" in the page directive or in web.config.

more information here:
http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation

Comment: thanks for your reply !! I have other controls in page which will be validated if I use ValidateRequest="false"...right ??

Comment: ValidateRequest is a way to prevent script attacks; if you disable it you accept insicure input. Validators (ASP:RequiredFieldValidator, ASP:CompareValidator and so on) will work. Look at my answer, anyway.

Comment: doing this at the page level will disable this validation for the entire page - and all controls on it - so be careful.  doing it in the web.config will disable for the entire site - and all controls on all pages - so be careful.  your validation will still execute.  emanuele greco makes good points and offers a nice alternative, so i am upvoting that answer too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode the content in Base64 before transferring it. But i'm not sure my solution is really good.

http://nolovelust.com/post/classic-asp-base64-encoder-decoder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the HTML being rejected server-side, as a security precaution.

You can disable this check by either:

Adding the following attribute to the page header `<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>`

or making the change application wide in the **Web.Config**:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```